# OkHttp3 & Retrofit: manually read from cache files

Tags: android, caching, retrofit, okhttp

I'm using Retrofit with OkHttp3 to download small text files. I want those files to be public so I don't store them in OkHttp cache directory (cache dir for APIs only). Write them to files is pretty easy but how to force OkHttp to use those saved files as cache files? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own code that skips the OkHttp request if you're cache has a hit. This may require a substantial amount of code.
..

Comment: yeah I know but that's not a what I want. I thought I could add an interceptor then create a RespondBody point to saved file but couldn't find a way to do that